# Propagate Small Change in Branch to All Other Branches in Git

Tags: git, branch

Let's say I have a small change of a couple of lines in a branch called A. I would like this particular change to be propagated to all other branches in the repo. This change is a part of other changes, which need not be included in the other branches.

How can I accomplish this? Are there different ways of doing this? Is one better than the others? In particular, can I accomplish it in one command for all the branches or will I need to do it piece-by-piece for each branch?

P.S. I am thinking of a patch and some merging, but am unsure.

Comment: Cherry-pick one commit, piece-by-piece for each branch.

Comment: @phd What will the history look like? Will all these branches have a common commit afterwards or will they get a new commit in their own commit line while remaining separate branches?

Comment: Separate branches, new independent commit for every cherry-pick operation.